# Facing Error Establishing a database Connection while migrating WordPress db

Tags: mysql, migration

I am trying to migrate WordPress website to the local machine. I am using XAMPP. After downloading db from hosting provider, I have imported the db to a new db created in phpmyadmin and also downloaded the codebase for WordPress. Now I am unable to connect to db. I have provided db login and password mentioned on the live site as well as users added in phpmyadmin into the **wp-config.php**. The local users have been granted access to the database. But still I am getting error establishing the connection with the db. Any suggestions.

Comment: Its a bit hard you help without details. Whats your config file  whats the error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.